# WCF Services In Background

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I'm trying to figure out how to run WCF Services as background Windows Services.

So far, in all the examples I've seen, for either a REST-WCF Web Service Host or a Duplex WCF Service Host, they end up running a small console that starts up the interface/service and waits for it to be closed.

How can I install the services and have them both running in the background?

I've seen this done with a normal service, it creates a few files: `ServiceInstaller`, `ProjectInstaller.cs`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR;

Here is how I do this, I have a Program class that allows me to start my application either as Windows Service (for production) or as a Console Application (for debugging and easy testing)

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var appMgr = new ApplicationManager();

        // pass --console and it runs as console!
        if (args.ToList().Contains("--console")) 
        {
            appMgr.Start();
            Console.Read();  // blocking here until key press
            appMgr.Stop();
        }
        else
        {
            var winService = new WinService(appMgr);
            ServiceBase.Run(winService);
        }
    }
}
```

My WinService looks like

```
public class WinService : ServiceBase
{
    private readonly ApplicationManager _appMgr;

    public WinService(ApplicationManager applicationManager)
    {
        if (applicationManager == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("applicationManager");

        _appMgr = applicationManager;
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        _appMgr.Start();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        _appMgr.Stop();
    }
}
```

We then go and implement an Application Manager. This keeps track of all the threads and workers you need, e.g.

```
public class ApplicationManager
{
    private WcfHost _bulkRulesWcfHost;

    public void Start()
    {
        // ...
        SetupWcf();             
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        // ...              
        if (_bulkRulesWcfHost != null) 
            _bulkRulesWcfHost.Stop();
    }

    private void SetupWcf()
    {
        // you can have many WCF services here      
        // ...

        IBulkRules syncService = new BulkRulesService(...);
        _bulkRulesWcfHost = new WcfHost(syncService, "BulkRulesService");
        _bulkRulesWcfHost.Start();
    }
}
```

At this point you should wonder, what's WcfHost

```
public class WcfHost
{
    private readonly ServiceHost _serviceHost;

    public WcfHost(object service, string name)
    {
        if (service == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("service");
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(name)) throw new ArgumentNullException("name");

        _serviceHost = new ServiceHost(service);
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public void Start()
    {
        if (_serviceHost != null)
            _serviceHost.Open();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        if (_serviceHost != null)
            _serviceHost.Close();
    }
}
```

Job's done. The only bit missing is configuration in the XML, I store it app.config

```xml
<configuration>    
  <system.serviceModel>    
    <services>           
        ...
      </service>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        ...
      </serviceBehaviors>      
    </behaviors>

    <bindings>
      ...
    </bindings>

  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks! In the application manager, if I wanted multiple services, would I have multiple `_bulkRulesWcfHost` global variables? And then have a similar three lines as you do in `SetupWcf()`?

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I do. I have about 3 or 4. Each call WCF service `Open` will run WCF plumbing code in its own thread.